# new to python and i am getting an attribute error

Tags: python

class newnode:

```
def _init_(self):
    self.x=1
def nextmethod(self,value):
    self.result=value+self.x
    print(self.result)
```

def main():

```
node1=newnode()
node1.nextmethod(6)
```

if **name**=='**main**':

```
main()
```

> C:/Users/hp/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 5, in nextmethod
>       self.result=value+self.x
>
> AttributeError: 'newnode' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: please reformat your code

Comment: The `init` method has two underscores not one. So write `def __init__(self)` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code:

```
class newnode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=1
    def nextmethod(self,value):
        self.result=value+self.x
        print(self.result)

def main():
    node1=newnode()
    node1.nextmethod(6)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Remember that `init` has double underscores.